# Android utils class

Tags: java, android

I have created a `Utils` class, which consists of `progressDialog` and `AlertDialog`:

```
public class Utils {


    public static ProgressDialog dialog;
    private static AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private static AlertDialog alert;

    public static void showLoader(Activity activity) {
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            dialog.setMessage(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);

        }
        dialog.show();
    }


    public static void hideLoader() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }

    public static void showOKMessageandBack(String message, final Context activity, final Class activityClass) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        if (message.length() <= 0)
            builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alert.hide();
                hideLoader();
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    public static void showAlertDialog(final Context context , String title , String message  ){

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // setting Dialog title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // setting Dialog message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot ask us to add code to your class, though we can review it :) I edited that part out of your question and corrected some of the spelling mistakes it had.

Comment: thank you for advice , I edit my question , I need review this class  , is their any way to make looks code better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm looking at this class and I'm confused.
The reason why is that I'm doing web programming so a dialog can be asked on different sessions.
In that case this class is useless.

In stead of holding your `ProgressDialog` and `AlertDialog` in your class as static variable, just return them in the method.
Then your

```
public static void hideLoader()
```

should be changed to :

```
public static void hideLoader(ProgressDialog dialog)
```

So with a small refactoring you create a class what could be good for multiple users application.
Other advantage is you can call the method multiple times, where in your setup this was impossible and even dangereous.

### Naming your class :

A class `Utils` is just so poor chosen.
If you see a class name like that, what do you expect what's in it?
It could be Utils for Strings like [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) or more like [MathUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html)?
As you see at this name, you already know what to expect from it.
A better name could be `DialogUtil`

### Constants :

In android there is a class [`R.string`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) who have a lot of constants.
In stead of doing this :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

You could do :

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

It's cleaner code who saves a little amount of memory because you don't need to recreate the `String` every time you call the method.

Answer (score 4):

## Static variables

The variables `builder` and `alert` should not be static, as they are only used in one function and do not persist.

The one place you use `alert` past the end of the function is in the callback function.  But you shouldn't be using it there:

> ```
>            alert.hide();
> ```

should be:

```
            dialog.hide();
```